# Why am I not receiving a 404 error using this rewrite rule in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wrote a rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file which hides the `.php` extension in the URL.

My code works perfectly, but, to my surprise, I am not receiving a 404 error using the following rewrite rule when the URL contains a query string.

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
```

---

I tested the rewrite rule using a tool to find and replace strings using regular expressions:

- Find what: `^([^\.]+)$`
- Replace with: `$1.php`

This matches `index?foo=bar` and replaces it with `index?foo=bar.php` (note the `.php` at the end). So, `example.com/index?foo=bar` should redirect me to `example.com/index?foo=bar.php`.

Now I expected a 404 error, but everything seems to be fine. For some reason it knew that the URL contained a query string and redirected me to `example.com/index.php?foo=bar`.

What is happening here?